How to select Vertices that get deselected after duplicating mesh
How do I select vertices that have been deselected after I duplicated that part of the mesh ?
I have duplicated a part of the mesh and separated that part of the mesh from the original mesh.
After doing so, the same vertices on the original mesh aren’t selected anymore. Is there a way to make them remain selected after duplicating them? And not having to manually select one by one again. It’s a complex mesh.

Create a vertex group.

Select the vertices once
Go to the data tab of the object
Create a new vertext group and rename it
"Assign" the selected points to the new gropus (with weight = 1)
Whenever you need, you can click "select" to select all the points of a group



Thank you so much !
